# Source for Magento 2.1.6 API documentation

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.1.6

We are using Magento 2.1.6 version for our e-commerce website, now the problem is I have to implement some new APIs for the logged in user but I am not able to find any API documentation for Magento 2.1.x versions. Every documentation on the website in either 2.2 or 2.3 version.

Please share if you have any reference to any of the API documentation for 2.1.x versions.

Thank you